# ArangoDB 3 CRUD in Angular 7

Tags: node.js, arangodb, angular7, foxx

I have an Angular 7 project up am running in production and I’m trying to determine the best way to connect to ArangoDB securely for CRUD operations. I’m looking for a best approach and working code example. Everything out there seems to be for AngularJS and I have failed to adapt it (it’s also probably not a best approach), I’m also not sure how to implement foxx for Angular 7. Any help or direction would be appreciated. I’ve searched everything, not sure what I am missing, I can only seem to work with ArangoDB via the web UI and the CLI, not from server script in the application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: `Everything out there seems to be for AngularJS` - don't you mean ArangoJS, the official ArangoDB JavaScript driver?

Comment: No I mean when I looking for help connecting Angular 7 to ArangoDB using anything including ArangoJS all the examples are with AngularJS (way outdated version of Angular).

Comment: Angular 1 is referred as Angular.JS (also written as Angular.js or AngularJS). It is an old version and still get updates. Angular 2+ versions are simply called Angular. Angular is an incompatible rewrite of AngularJS. It is a TypeScript-based open-source front-end web application platform.

Comment: Exactly my problem @BugBuddy. Everything I find is for AngularJS completely incompatible for my needs with Angular. I specified Angular 7 to be certain no one would think I am looking for Angular 1 / AngulrJS